# How do I retrieve the ListItem value dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code:

```
<asp:BulletedList ID="filingList" runat="server" DisplayMode="LinkButton"
            onclick="filingList_Click">
</asp:BulletedList>

<asp:Literal ID="filingLiteral" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

and in the backend I fill the bulleted list with ListItems (where `AlternateFileUrl` is a url string that points to text formatted in html):

```
foreach (ShortFiling file in filingArray)
{
    filingList.Items.Add(new ListItem(file.Type.ToString() + " " 
    + file.Date.ToString(), file.AlternateHtmlFileUrl));
}
```

How do I access the text of the `value` of the item that's clicked on in the `filingList` then set it to the `asp:Literal` control? Here is the empty event handler that I defined and assume that I need to put the code in to set the asp:literal to the value of the specified ListItem.

```
protected void filingList_Click(object sender, BulletedListEventArgs e)
{
    //put code here to set the asp:Literal text to 
    //the value of the item that is clicked on 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protected void filingList_Click(object sender, BulletedListEventArgs e)
{
    var value = filingList.Items[e.Index].Value;
    filingLiteral.Text = value;
}
```

**UPDATE** 2

Ok you want the text from that URL, keep your markup as it was and change the code behind to this:

```
protected void filingList_Click(object sender, BulletedListEventArgs e)
{
    var value = filingList.Items[e.Index].Value;

    using(var client = new WebClient())
    {
        string downloadString = client.DownloadString(value);

        filingLiteral.Text = downloadString;  
    }
}
```

You will need to add the `System.Net` namespace.

Comment: This is somewhat helpful. The URL points to something like this http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/789019/0001193125-06-213894.txt and I would like to take that text and put it in the `asp:literal` control. With the code above, it will just display the link.

Comment: hm, now it's just showing a clickable link. I'd like to show the returned markup.

Comment: oh I see, do you want the text from that URL in the literal?

Comment: wow this is getting there. however it's still including the top portion of the file when I'd only like to access the <HTML></HTML>

Comment: Ok then, this will do it: `filingLiteral.Text = downloadString.Substring(downloadString.IndexOf("<HTML>"));` but you will need something more robust. I think you probably can figure it out on your own =D. You are almost there

Comment: What do you mean by more robust? Thanks very much btw.

Comment: I'm not sure if it can happen, but what if instead of "<HTML>" it comes as "<html>" the index would not match.  You can use the `IndexOf` overload that specifies `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` it works but I don't know if `IndexOf` is the best possible way of getting just the html.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly, you would just handle the click event of the BulletedList control, like:

```
protected void filingList_Click(object sender, BulletedListEventArgs e)
{
    BulletedList bull = (BulletedList)sender;
    ListItem li = bull.Items(e.Index);
    filingLiteral.Text = li.Value;
}
```